# Putting individual customers transactions into an array

Tags: arrays, sas

I have a dataset consisting of some transactions done by customers

I want to put these transactions into an array from 1 to 50. So 1 customers can have 50 transactions or more. I want my output dataset to be 1 row per customer with the value of each transaction being put into a column.

Finally what I am trying to do is to have these transaction values in an array. With the array being reset back to 0 upon first.cust_id. Any idea how I can go about doing this. This is what I have so far but it is giving me errors. Let's assume the initial dataset has just cust_id and transaction_amount fields.

The code represents just array initiation. I am doing a few calculations with the arrays afterwards.

```
data check;
    set transactions;
    by cust_id;
    array trans[*] trans1-trans50;
    retain array_counter;
    if first.cust_id then do;
       do i=1 to dim(trans);
          trans[i]=0; 
       end;
       array_counter=1;
    end;
    trans[array_counter] = transaction_amount;
    array_counter=sum(array_counter,1);
    if last.cust_id;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need a `retain`.  Without that, your values of the `trans` array will get cleared out every data step loop.

Second, if you say "50 or more" transactions; well, your array bounds only allow 50, so what does it do for 51?

This works, and I set it to 30 per customer so you can see the 0's.  If you set that initial 1 to 30 loop to 1 to 60, you'll get out of bounds errors.

```
data transactions;
  call streaminit(7);
  do cust_id = 1 to 10;
    do transaction = 1 to 30;
      transaction_amount = rand('uniform');
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
data check;
    set transactions;
    by cust_id;
    retain trans1-trans50;
    array trans[*] trans1-trans50;
    retain array_counter;
    if first.cust_id then do;
       do i=1 to dim(trans);
          trans[i]=0; 
       end;
       array_counter=1;
    end;
    trans[array_counter] = transaction_amount;
    array_counter=sum(array_counter,1);
    if last.cust_id;
run;
```

Comment: I have now solved it. Are you sure you need to use retain on the array? Isn't one of the features of arrays the fact that they are automatically retained?      

Your point about having a limit of 50 is an issue I couldn't figure out the answer to. I could always check the dataset for the maximum number of transactions and have that as the dimension size.
What is the point of having trans[*] instead of trans[50] if you're declaring 50 variables anyway?

Comment: @Mobix No, arrays are not automatically retained.  Only _temporary_ arrays are automatically retained.

Comment: As far as the limit of 50 - yes, you should probably check the maximum limit and store it in a macro variable.

Comment: As for the [*], that's just my automatic default, you're right that it doesn't serve any purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things are wrong in your code. For starters, in order to use `first`/`last` processing, you need a `by` statement. Then, in order to get only one row per customer, you need to also `retain` your array variables and output only on `last.cust_id`:

```
data check;
    set transactions;
        by cust_id;
    array trans[*] trans1-trans50;
    retain array_counter trans1-trans50;
    if first.cust_id then do;
       do i=1 to dim(trans);
          trans[i]=0; 
       end;
       array_counter=1;
    end;
    trans[array_counter] = transaction_amount;
    array_counter+1;
    if last.cust_id then output;
run;
```

Comment: Yes you're right. In my code I have if last.cust_id; the by cust_id; statement. My question is how come it's not initiating the array variables and keeps on giving me the array out of bounds error.

Comment: I don't know where you get that error. I tried your edited code on some sample data and I don't get any error. However I don't get your desired result because, although you edited your code to add the `by` statement and the `if last`, you still do not retain the `trans-trans` variables (see my answer). EDIT: as joe pointed out, if you have more than 50 transactions for one customer, you'll obviously get an out of bounds error on your array.